# Query in oracle for required data in specific formate

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have data in table as below :

Three Columns

```
 date1 fromdate value
 ---------------------
 14     0       150
 14     2       150
 14     3       150
 14     4       120
 14     5       120
 14     6       150
 14     7       150
```

I need to write sql query to get data in below format:

```
 Date1 fromdate todate value
 ----------------------------
 14     0       3      150
 14     4       5      120
 14     6       7      150
```

Is this possible to do with SQL query in oracle ?

Comment: which database? SQL server, Oracle, My SQL?

Comment: As mentioned in Headline ... Its Oracle

Comment: You need to explain how you got the output... make it easier for us to help you...

Comment: The "environment" (what products you use etc.) should be put into the tags - that's where people look for it (not in the title); added `Oracle` tag for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split your rows with the value 150 into two separate sections. You can do this by using analytic functions. The `lead` function allows you to look at the value of the next row by some order. In this case you want to find when you have a different value order by your fromdate:

```
select lead(value) over (order by fromdate) from tab;
```

You can then compare this to the current value to see when they change, outputting a discriminator when they do:

```
select value, case when ld <> value or ld is null then rownum end c from (
  select value, lead(value) over (order by fromdate) ld from tab
)

VALUE, C
-----------
150    null
150    null
150    3
120    null
120    5
150    null
150    7
```

You then need to "fill out" the discriminator to replace the nulls. This can be done with analytics again, selecting the `min` discriminator value by fromdate descending. You can then group by this value to give you the output you want:

```
select date1, value, d, min(fromdate), max(fromdate)
from (
  select date1, fromdate, value,
         --"fill down" the discriminator, so you can group by it at the next level 
         min(c) over (order by fromdate desc) d 
  from (
    select date1, fromdate, value, ld, 
           --compare the next value with the current, if they're different
           --show an indicator
           case when value <> ld or ld is null then rownum else null end c
    from (
      select date1, fromdate, value,lead(value) over (order by fromdate) ld
      from tab
    )
  )
)
group by date1, value, d
```

Comment: WOW......... gr8.............. thanks ..... thanks so much .. THis is what exactly i want ..

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT
  Date1, 
  MIN(fromdate) FromDate, 
  MAX(fromdate) ToDate, 
  "Value"
FROM
  "YourTable" 
GROUP BY Date1, "Value";
```

Comment: Thanks techdo .... thank u soo much for ur valuable answer but i want exact output as i mentioned ..with ur query it return only two rows that is not correct.

Comment: As per ur query it give two rows: 1st one with  0-7  and other row with 4-5. i dont want like this way .

Comment: @user2035000 it is returning exactly what his query is requesting; however, his query will not work in your situation given the data set.

Comment: Furthermore, I do not see any SQL way to do this.

Comment: @AlbertoPonte - don't be so quick to dismiss SQL; this is entirely possible with it.